# With a Fertility Rate of 2.2, all else being held equal, what is the population doubling time?

Tags: population

I get confused with the math here, and wasn't able to find an easy fertility rate to pop. growth to pop. doubling time online. If anyone can walk me through the answer here, that would be very useful.

Comment: Fertility alone is not enough to answer this question. You also need to provide mortality rates. In our current world fertility of 2.2 is what is needed to keep the population stable (not growing and not decreasing) in the majority of developed countries.

Comment: just use a compound interest calculator... it works with population too, not just money

Comment: Yes but you have to first convert fertility rate into population growth rate, which I don't know how to do

Comment: 2.5  children per women is considered the replacement rate in modern demographics. That means 2.2 children per women will lead to a net population DECREASE.

Comment: really? why is that? I thought 2.1 was replacement rate

Answer (score 6):

The "replacement" birth rate is naively 2 per woman. This is because males and females are approximately equally likely to be born (males have a slight edge, but also die before adulthood slightly more often.)

So if women are half the population, then on average each women must give birth twice to replace the current male and female population.

However, this must be adjusted to deal with some realities:

- Children born that fail to reproduce, due to early death.
- Accident or disease causing infertility.
- Lack of opportunity.
- Homosexuality.
- Choice; like men or women that join religious orders prohibiting sexual intercourse).

So typically the replacement rate is considered 2.1. If the rate is bumped up to 2.2, then we need to know the rate of increase. It is 2.2 / 2.1, which is 1.0476 per "generation", which I will get to later.

The math is ln(2)/ln(1.0476), the "2" is for doubling. The answer here is 14.90, which is the number of generations this has to repeat.

So, what is a generation? We look at the birth-to-birth time; meaning the average time between a female being born to that same female giving birth.

We only consider women because they are the only ones that can give birth, and the father's age does not matter. Nor does it matter whether all males reproduce; 1% of them may do all the reproducing and 99% do none, that won't matter either. We only care about the average age of women giving birth to their first child.

We can estimate this at [23,](https://www.cdc.gov/nchs/nsfg/key_statistics/b.htm#agefb) although it has been increasing recently; women are having their first child later.

But if we use 23, then 23*14.9 generations is 343 years; and that is how long it takes for the entire population to double.

But obviously, you can use your own age of first birth in your story, if you want a longer or shorter time than that.

Or, you can use a higher fertility rate. Even a small increase in the fertility rate can have a dramatic effect. Keeping all the above the same but using a 2.3 fertility rate, the growth rate (2.3/2.1)=1.0952, and ln(2)/ln(1.0952) is 7.62 generations. Multiplied by a generation length of 23 is 175 years instead of 343.

Answer (score 1):

**Approximately 350 years**

Assuming that you use the default parameters in this simulator: https://www.ined.fr/en/everything_about_population/population-games/tomorrow-population/

This assumes that you use the default Mortality Rate, Life Expectancy and Gender Ratio and the current population distribution of the world as it is in 2022. All of these factors affect the calculation. Fertility rate is defined as children per woman, so the gender ratio of Males to Females is important here. Also, the minimum fertility rate for growth is 2.1 not 2.0 because not everyone manages to reproduce.

Comment: Thanks very much. I knew 2.1 was replacement, but wasn't sure what the impact of slightly over replacement would be. What about, say, a 2.3 or 2.4 fertility rate? (I tried to do it myself on the simulator, but couldn't figure it out..)

Comment: @JshupacFuture-Economics Just input whatever numbers you want and run the simulator until the population number doubles. Then subtract 2022 from the year given.